# How to do the sensitive analysis for the prior?

Tags: bayesian, hierarchical-bayesian, jags

I understand bayesian people always do the sensitive analysis for the study.
However, I am confused how we set the sensitive analysis.

My question is how we set the parameter's for the sensitive analysis?

Is there any applied Bayesian hierarchical paper we can see for the sensitive analysis?

For example: we have a prior for the m~ dnorm(0,1)

the possible sensitive analysis

set m~ dnorm(0,100)

set m~ dnorm(100,1)

set m~ dnorm(100000,100000)

set m~ dgamma(0.5,1)

which sensitive analysis make more sense?

Thanks

Comment: This paper "The Importance of Prior Sensitivity Analysis in Bayesian Statistics: Demonstrations Using an Interactive Shiny App" (https://www.frontiersin.org/articles/10.3389/fpsyg.2020.608045/full) with an Shiny app might be helpful for you.

Comment: I'm a big fan of prior predictive checks. Andrew Gelman and his collaborators write about these a lot, e.g., http://www.stat.columbia.edu/~gelman/bayescomputation/bdachapter6.pdf